# Searching with more than 2 part names in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm currently looking to implement a search function on my website.
I have it working with 1 word/name, but I can't seem to figure out how to split and identify certain parts of the search string.

*Example:*

I have a user in my database with the name "Steve de Vette"

(My country has words in between almost all of the first and last names but not always, and sometimes more than one. ex: "Kees van der Berg") But his name is of course split up in multiple parts. "vNaam", "Tvoegsel"(meaning the "de" or "van der") and "aNaam".

This complicates things a bit for me, since I now have to split the search string, which on it's own isn't a big deal. But I need to know how I can get the correct results every time.

So I guess it comes down to this: **How can I make it so that the name is split up** like it should, or maybe there's a way to strip these thing all together, but for the likes of me I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

EDIT:

I have tried just exploding the name and searching with multiple OR_LIKE clauses. This works until I have no "tussenvoegsel" and one of the Like statements reads "OR `anaam` LIKE '%%'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

split the string with explode and search for the first and last item.

```
    $string1 = "Steve de Vette";
    $string2 = "Kees van der Berg";

    $ex1 = explode(" ", $string2);
    $nr = count($ex1);

    echo $ex1[0]; //firstname
    echo ' ';
    echo $ex1[$nr-1]; //lastname
```

Comment: Verry simple and clean, I'm going to use this until I run into any problems. People have wierd names :S

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the PHP string searching funciton.

```
$pos = strpos($string, $character);
```

You could use this to find the first space in the name. So if you take "Steve de Vette", you could first find Steve as the first name, then the rest of the string you could search again or keep the rest of it as the last name.

This is a snippet of code taken from my own site.

```
$fname = strstr($entry," ",true); <-- finds the first name (all characters up to the first space)
$len = strlen($fname) + 1; <-- skips over the space to the last name
$entrylen = strlen($entry); <-- gets the length of the search string used
$sname = substr($entry, $len, $entrylen); <-- gets the rest of the string (last name)
```

Hope you find this helpful

Comment: This is what I have already done, sadly I'm looking for a way that makes it possible for people to leave out the "de" and "van der" or even fill in the wrong thing seeing as it's a search function and not a lookup function. Maybe I should just cram them together. Thanks for your contribution anyway!

Comment: Oh I see! Sorry I couldn't help much. Hope you find the solution soon!

Comment: Try looking to something called Apache Solr search, that may help.

Answer (score 0):

What i do is strip out any spaces all together. I store spaces in my database like normal but use the replace feature when searching to strip out spaces. then strip out spaces from the search field as well and use the like with the wild card on the right hand side. I try to make the search as simple as possible. searching with one word seems to work better all together so forcing one word seems to be the thing that works for me.